# Angular reactive form for control

Tags: angular

A social number input field must have format like below condition in reactive forms:

- Format must be ###-##-####.
- Limit size to 9 digits without the dashes (11 with dashes)
- User does not enter dash (dash is not a numeric value

Can anyone please help me in code of this format and requirement for this control

```
form name: ownsForm
object:obj
formcontrol name========(social: this.Obj.social),
```

#### html

```html
<input matInput 
       placeholder="Social " 
       class="form-control input-sm" 
       formControlName="social">
```

Please provide the code in reactive angular form for `.ts` file and HTML file.
I am taking input from the user.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you've tried so far to solve this problem?  Asking people to write code for you on SO generally won't get a response.

Answer (score 0):

Had you try ngx-Mask package?

Here i had created simple stackblitz demo as per your requirement.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zwtrch

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are talking about angular Pipes? this is what we can use for formatting, regular expressions, and transforms.

https://angular.io/guide/pipes